# Generate slug function - String specify multiple delimiters

Tags: php, string, function, preg-replace, delimiter

I want to specify multiple delimiters that are allowed in the slug. So that when a user from the likes of Instagram registers, they have exact same username. At the moment all underscores are changed to '.' however, I would like to add '_' and '-' into the mix as many accounts on both Twitter and Instagram have the underscore.

```
function generate_slug($string, $delimiter = '.') {
```

I've tried a number of things with the likes of both below.

```
function generate_slug($string, $delimiter = '(_|.)') {
function generate_slug($string, $delimiter = '[_|.]') {
```

Comment: Have you tried any approach in that direction? Do you have some code that you've tried and it doesn't work for some reason? Also please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes @DanD. I have  I've looked through here and tried many ways to get it to work. Whatever I put in either adds to the generated link or there's a complete whiteout. Tried things like '[_|.] & (.|_)

Comment: ok, but please create a complete question then, and paste in some code of what you've tried and doesn't work, so it's easier to get some help, rather than having someone create a piece of code for your question from scratch.

Comment: Added what I have tried to get to work @DanD.

Comment: Both the above two I tried worked. A string further down the script was affecting the delimiters.